# Query to determine cumulative changes to records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the following table containing the example rows, I’m looking for a query to give me the aggregate results of changes made to the same record.   All changes are made against a base record in another table (results table), so the contents of the results table are not cumulative.

**Base Records (from which all changes are made)**

[image]

Edited Columns highlighted

[image]

I’m looking for a query that would give me the cumulative changes (in order by date). This would be the resulting rows:

[image]

Any help appreciated!

UPDATE---------------

Let me offer some clarification.  The records being edited exist in one table, let's call that [dbo].[Base].  When a person updates a record from [dbo].[Base], his updates go into [dbo].[Updates]. Therefore, a person is always editing from the base table.

At some point, let's say once a day, we need to calculate the sum of changes with the following rule:

For any given record, determine the latest change for each column and take the latest change.  If no change was made to a column, take the value from [dbo].[Base].  So, one way of looking at the [dbo].[Updates] table would be to see only the changed columns.

[image]

Please let's not discuss the merits of this approach, I realize it's strange. I just need to figure out how to determine the final state of each record.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 partitioned by `id` ordered by `datemodified` descending, and then picking row=1?

Comment: For record ID=100  the address was changed to "123 First" on 1/20/2019. Why is this not the expected result? I do not quite understand the logic behind this.

Comment: So your change table is full of null values?

Comment: @IsItGreyOrGray, it could be, but not at the moment, the entire row is saved to the update table.

Comment: So you have to identify the most recent version of the column that is not the same as the base?

Comment: @IsItGreyOrGray correct.  And columns that haven't changed.

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: @xgp see if the answer I left helps get you in the right direction.

Comment: I still don't completely get it. How would the record in the Updates table look like, if someone edited the Address "123 First St." back to its original value "123 First"? It would be indistinguishable from the record in the Base table and not be recognized as change!

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes is totally right, here. The only method one can currently use to identify whether the value has changed is to compare it to the original. Unless you made a mistake and should have highlighted the address on 1/20/2019 that OlivierJacot-Descombes already indicated as a change yesterday.

Comment: Either the right record is just the last Update record or we are still missing an important piece of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is dirty, but you can give this a shot (test here: https://rextester.com/MKSBU15593)

I use a CTE to do an initial `CROSS JOIN` of the Base and Update tables and then a second to filter it to only the rows where the IDs match. From there I use `FIRST_VALUE()` for each column, partitioned by the ID value and ordered by a CASE expression (if the Base column value matches the Update column value then 1 else 0) and the Datemodified column to get the most recent version of the each column.

It spits out

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE Base
(
    ID INT
    ,FNAME VARCHAR(100)
    ,LNAME VARCHAR(100)
    ,ADDRESS VARCHAR(100)
    ,RATING INT
    ,[TYPE] VARCHAR(5)
    ,SUBTYPE VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Base
VALUES
(   100,'John','Doe','123 First',3,'Emp','W2'),
(   200,'Jane','Smith','Wacker Dr.',2,'Emp','W2');

CREATE TABLE Updates
(
    ID INT
    ,DATEMODIFIED DATE
    ,FNAME VARCHAR(100)
    ,LNAME VARCHAR(100)
    ,ADDRESS VARCHAR(100)
    ,RATING INT
    ,[TYPE] VARCHAR(5)
    ,SUBTYPE VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Updates
VALUES
(   100,'1/15/2019','John','Doe','123 First St.',3,'Emp','W2'),
(   200,'1/15/2019','Jane','Smyth','Wacker Dr.',2,'Emp','W2'),
(   100,'1/17/2019','Johnny','Doe','123 First',3,'Emp','W2'),
(   200,'1/19/2019','Jane','Smith','2 Wacker Dr.',2,'Emp','W2'),
(   100,'1/20/2019','Jon','Doe','123 First',3,'Cont','W2');


WITH merged AS
(
    SELECT b.ID AS IDOrigin 
        ,'1/1/1900' AS DATEMODIFIEDOrigin
        ,b.FNAME AS FNAMEOrigin
        ,b.LNAME AS LNAMEOrigin
        ,b.ADDRESS AS ADDRESSOrigin
        ,b.RATING AS RATINGOrigin
        ,b.[TYPE]  AS TYPEOrigin
        ,b.SUBTYPE AS SUBTYPEOrigin
        ,u.*
    FROM base b
    CROSS JOIN
    dbo.Updates u
), filtered AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM merged
    WHERE IDOrigin = ID
)

SELECT distinct
    ID
    ,FNAME = FIRST_VALUE(FNAME) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CASE WHEN FNAME = FNAMEOrigin THEN 1 ELSE 0 end, datemodified desc)
    ,LNAME = FIRST_VALUE(LNAME) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CASE WHEN LNAME = LNAMEOrigin THEN 1 ELSE 0 end, datemodified desc)
    ,ADDRESS = FIRST_VALUE(ADDRESS) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CASE WHEN ADDRESS = ADDRESSOrigin THEN 1 ELSE 0 end, datemodified desc)
    ,RATING = FIRST_VALUE(RATING) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CASE WHEN RATING = RATINGOrigin THEN 1 ELSE 0 end, datemodified desc)
    ,[TYPE] = FIRST_VALUE([TYPE]) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CASE WHEN [TYPE] = TYPEOrigin THEN 1 ELSE 0 end, datemodified desc)
    ,SUBTYPE = FIRST_VALUE(SUBTYPE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CASE WHEN SUBTYPE = SUBTYPEOrigin THEN 1 ELSE 0 end, datemodified desc)
FROM filtered
```

Comment: you SQL Wizards never cease to amaze.  I don't know what the heck you're doing here, but it seems to work.  I'll have to study this. Thanks!

Comment: You should unmark this as answer. We've still got questions in the original post's comments and I'm pretty sure this LOOKS good, but is potentially (and probably) busted.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just want the last record?

```
select e.*
from edited e
where e.datemodified = (select max(e2.datemodified)
                        from edited e2
                        where e2.id = e.id
                       );
```

Comment: No, because I need the cumulative edits for each row.  Each "edited" row is editing from the base record, not from the previously edited row, hope that makes sense. In other words, the person editing is not editing the latest record, he is editing the base row.  I have to determine the sum of all edits.  Where the last record counts is that the latest edit to a column wins.

Comment: How do you see if someone restores a value as it was in the first record? How do you see it was edited? E.g. the address is changed back to "123 First".

Comment: Please see my update, I hope this adds clarification.